# twitter card not showing the meta data I provide it with

Tags: twitter, next.js, meta-tags

I couldn't find what is the cause of my bug: I have the following page on https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator
[image]

Whereas https://metatags.io/ gives clear results
[image]

It is for this link if you are curious about the meta fields
https://weally.org/request/62662c68c76ac6001d6c711d/detail

If I try a link on twitter directly, it shows a generic image and description available only for the homepage
[image]

I'm using next.js with the `<Head>` component to 'override' meta fields:

```
import Head from 'next/head'
```

Actually what I see from the source code of my SSR generated page is that they are not overridden but written twice
https://weally.org/request/62e37e27d3cd38001ef78bcf/detail
[image: capture of meta fields]

From my source code, I don't see anything I can do to change that behavior:

```
export default function EditRequest(props) {
    const router = useRouter()
    const {t} = useTranslation('common');
    const {issueId} = router.query
    if (issueId === undefined) {
        return <DisplayState state={DEFAULT_STATES.ERROR} message={"Wrong address: request not specified"}/>
    }

    return (
        <MainLayout>
            <Head>
                <title>{props.meta.title}</title>
                <meta property="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>
                <meta property="twitter:site" content={props.fullUrl}/>
                <meta property="twitter:title" content={props.meta.title}/>
                <meta property="twitter:description" content={props.meta.desc}/>
                <meta property="twitter:image" content={props.meta.img}/>

                <meta name="description" content={props.meta.seoDesc}/>
                <meta name="title" property="og:title" content={props.meta.title}/>
                <meta name="description" property="og:description" content={props.meta.desc}/>
                <meta name="image" property="og:image" content={props.meta.img}/>
                <meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
                <meta property="og:url" content={props.fullUrl}/>
                <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US"/>
            </Head>
            <IssueDetail issueId={issueId}/>
        </MainLayout>
    )
```

Is there anyway to tell twitter to read the ones at the top?

Comment: So I disabled js in dev mode, and metadata is not loaded correctly, so if twitter doesn't execute javascript this might be an explanantion. I'll check that out

Comment: The Twitter card crawler is a server side app that does not execute JavaScript.

Comment: Regression fixed on my side, now SSR renders correctly (with js disabled), but I still see a generic card: meta tags in a picture I joined

Comment: Twitter's crawler will use the last set of values that it sees (which in your case is the generic information since the tags appear twice). I'm not familiar with your platform to know how or where the "second" set of values is coming from, sorry.

Comment: Try adding a unique `key` prop to each meta tag, e.g. `<meta key="twitterSite" property="twitter:site" content={props.fullUrl}/>`. Also, are you adding meta tags anywhere else in the app? If so, use the same `key` props for each meta tag.

Comment: Thank you @juliomalves You're right, but there's a bias: I cannot have head tags in _document. 

I'm saying that for those in my situation: beware of this behavior of the Head component that doesn't override meta tags in the _document file.
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9794

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so causes were multiple:

First I had duplicate meta tags not overriding each other

To solve it I added a key property to tell next/head component which meta tags    are the same and should be overridden, but this too didn't work

So I had to remove the meta tags from _document and move them to individual pages as described here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9794

Answer (score -1):

Your Twitter card for that link works fine - paste the link into a new Tweet and you will see it render.

Twitter's card validator no longer shows the rendered cards as it was not the same as what you would see if you pasted it into a Tweet, so the validator now lets you submit the URL and confirm that tags can be found. Here's [the announcement](https://twittercommunity.com/t/card-validator-preview-removal/175006) about that:

> We’ve recently removed the preview functionality from the Card
> Validator. Previews are still available in the Tweet Composer and the
> Card Validator remains accessible for other debugging purposes

Comment: The preview I have is not at all the one that is present in the meta tags: it's the one from the home page. I modified the question to integrate a capture since I cannot paste it in a comment